# Spring Cloud Configuration client for dotnet/c#

Tags: c#, .net, spring-cloud

I have a mixed technology stack and have an existing spring cloud config server set up. I also have dotnet/c# clients and I need them to work with the config server.

I was unable to find example dotnet code which understands the format and bootstraps at runtime. What I can do, worst case, is translate the server http response.

I see a lot of references to a steeltoe library but seems to be focussed on the server/provider.

Any ideas/example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is a couple months late, but the Steeltoe Configuration library is a client for Spring Cloud Config Server, I think it is what you're looking for: https://steeltoe.io/docs/steeltoe-configuration/#2-0-config-server-provider

There are samples for ASP.NET 4.x and ASP.NET Core here: https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/master/Configuration/src